# Extensive list of financial derivatives and what method is used to value them

Tags: derivatives

What I'm imagining is a long list of different types of financial instruments traded on the market along with the model(s) that is industry standard for valuing it. Something like:

European equity options  : Black-Schooles model

American equity options : Binomial options pricing model

Asian equity options: Monte-Carlo simulation

Swaption : Black-76 model

Bermudan Swaption: Lattice-based term structure

and so forth. Has anyone come across something like this?

Comment: Asian options are very often priced using moment matching.

Answer (score 2):

Not an exhausting list, and just a little dated, but a very extensive list of various kinds of options and the methods used to price them can be found in [*The Complete Guide to Option Pricing Formulas* by Espen Gaarder Haug](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071389970).