# Is there some sort of index of products, their description, and pricing?

Tags: options, fixed-income, swaps, valuation

I'm imagining some sort of site where you can look up all sorts of products that are traded (swaps, bonds, options, and all the variations that they exist in), and then the site gives an extremely short summary (e.g. 2-3 sentences) of what the product's does, and then a concise formula for its valuation.

This sounds like it would be very helpful to get a good overview of everything. Does something like this exist online? Or perhaps a book in which one can find all this?

To be clear, I am not asking for anything that is substantially detailed, just a few sentences of description so that one can go "aha so thats how it works" and then look it up in an actual book if more details are required.

Comment: It's a good question, but I think it's a dupicate: Does this answer your question? [Extensive list of financial derivatives and what method is used to value them](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54356/extensive-list-of-financial-derivatives-and-what-method-is-used-to-value-them)

Comment: Maybe it's a suitable topic for Meta - should we have Community Wiki's for 1 list of products 2 book recommendations and reviews

Comment: Isn't this what the internet is for?  Reference texts like Fabozzi exist (for FI instruments), but I'm not aware of any reference that covers assets from all classes